# With bundler, what's the best way to tell if a gem is "requirable"?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Say in my Gemfile I have

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec-core', require: false
end
```

Is there an easy way to see if the `test` group has been bundled? (like, in this case `bundle` may have been called with or without `--without test`).

I couldn't find one, therefore I started looking for whether or not `rspec-core` is requirable, and found a few apparent solutions:

```
 Bundler.definition.index.search("rspec-core")
 # or
 Gem.loaded_specs["rspec-core"]
```

What's the most stable API to determine if the gem is requirable?

(without trying to require it and rescuing `LoadError`)

Comment: Are you asking how to tell if a gem is "requirable" or if a group has been required?

Comment: I am asking if a gem is "requirable", I asked about groups rhetorically to give context.

Comment: Use Bundler if the gem you are searching for could be a dependency of one explicitly bundled.  Use Gem if the ruby file could ever be called outside the bundled context.

Comment: I would recommend using `Bundler.definition.index.search("rspec-core")` as more stable, it has not been changed since almost the beginning of mature bundler (2010) https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blame/master/lib/bundler/definition.rb, also a lot of other internal bundler methods use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and say `Gem.loaded_specs` is more reliable than going through bundler; I discovered a circumstance with bundler 1.12.5 where I have a gem from GitHub in one of the groups that I pass to `without`, this causes `Bundler.definition.index.search` to raise a `Bundler::PathError` citing the gem from GitHub that I intentionally am not bundling.

Answer (score 3):

When a Rails app is generated it typically includes a line that uses Rails.env to determine which group to require. It should look something like this `Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)`. This typically happens in the initialization of a Rails App. Here is a snippet of some code that does that:

```
class Rails::Boot
  def run
    load_initializer

    Rails::Initializer.class_eval do
      def load_gems
        @bundler_loaded ||= Bundler.require :default, Rails.env
      end
    end

    Rails::Initializer.run(:set_load_path)
  end
end
```

So if you Rails.env is test it will require all the gems in the test group.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out inconsistency in my question. I have updated it to clarify I was asking myself whether the group has been required, but whether it has been bundled.